# Why doesn't "f in (g or h)" give the result I expect?

Tags: python, operators

These statements are giving output but not what I expect. Can anyone explain why?

**Code**

```
f = "H"
g = "haritas"
h = "Haritas"

print(f in (g or h))
print(f in (g and h))
```

**Output**

```
False
True
```

Comment: what did you expect?

Comment: Check what `(g or h)` actually evaluates to!

Comment: `print((f in h) or (f in g))` `print((f in h) and (f in g))` this will work